# Error while trying to predict numbers: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I recently started studying ML during a youtube tutorial. Based on what was told in the tutorial, I decided to improve and apply to a kind of Guess Game.

The game has multiple scenarios and some numbers which player have to collect before he goes to the next stage. So I thought to apply this to ML and try to see what happens.

In my CSV file, I have 16 columns  (stage and 1 to 15 numbers) and lots of rows. So, to predict what is the numbers of the last stage (1988), I directly put into a "...predict([[1988]]))" and got the

```py
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead.
```

I know it's almost impossible to predict in this case, but my main goal here is to reduce the number of mistakes and see how good ML can be to solve this.

Could you guys show me what and where I'm doing wrong? To better explain, code is below:

```
import pandas
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier


game_data = pandas.read_csv('game_data2.csv')
game_list = game_data.drop(columns=['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 
                                    'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9', 'n10', 
                                     'n11', 'n12', 'n13', 'n14', 'n15'])

game_stage = game_data['STAGE']

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(game_stage, game_list)


predictions = model.predict([[1988]])
predictions
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape your `game_stage` variable into a 2D array before passing it into `model.fit()`.

If you modify your code like this, you don't get the error message:

```
import pandas
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np

# Read data
game_data = pandas.read_csv('game_data2.csv')
game_list = game_data.drop(columns=['n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9', 'n10', 'n11', 'n12', 'n13', 'n14', 'n15'])
game_stage = game_data['STAGE']

# Reshape into 2D array using numpy
game_stage = np.asarray(game_stage)
# -1 means this dimension is inferred from the data
game_stage = game_stage.reshape(-1,1)

# Train model
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(game_stage, game_list)

# Prediction
predictions = model.predict([[1988]])
predictions
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm no familiarized with NumPy, so, I haven't even tried it. 
I appreciate your time helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

You are just supposed to provide the predict method with the same 2D array, but with one value that you want to process (or more). In short, you can just replace

```
[1988]
```

With

```
[[1988]]
```

And it should work.

This answer became popular so I thought I'd add a little more explanation about ML. The short version: we can only use predict on data that is of the same dimensionality as the training data (X) was.

In the example in question, we give the computer a bunch of rows in X  and we show it the correct responses in y. When we want to predict using new values, our program expects the same - a bunch of rows. Even if we want to do it to just one row, that row has to be part of another array.